# determining logistic curve parameters from 3 points of data

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find the parameters, $L$, $k$, and $t_0$ that are present in a logistic function:

$y = \frac{L}{1+\exp\left(-k(t-t_0)\right)}$.

I have three points of data, namely: $(t,y) = (1,896.50),(2,1814.00),(3,1878.50)$.

Could I then solve the three resulting equations uniquely for the parameters $L,k,t_0$, or is this not possible, even numerically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be solvable because you have three points and three parameters, and the points satisfy monotonicity.  I get:

$$L = 1880.8216, k=3.3947179, t_0=1.0275293$$

I used [Stata's nonlinear regression](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/nonlinear-regression/) command for this, but you could do it by hand using [Gauss-Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) or something similar.  It should be relatively easy because the logistic function is differentiable everywhere.

There might be an analytical solution, but I don't know.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. My only confusion is that $L$ should be the maximum of the curve, so if you take $L=1880.8216$ as the solver gives, and now say you want to evaluate the curve at future times, like $t=4,5,6$ etc... couldn’t it be that future values exceed the maximum? Is the numerical solver assuming that $t=3$ is the terminal time? In other words, suppose I had 4 points or 5, does it matter which 3 points I choose to solve the equations above?

Comment: By definition, the value of the function won't exceed the maximum, no matter what you plug in for $t$. ;)  Try plugging in a huge value, like $t=1000$.

It doesn't matter which 3 points you use as long as they all lie on the same curve.  If your datapoints are subject to random deviations from the curve, you may get a different solution depending on which 3 points you choose.  For example, if you had 5 points, and they were "close to" lying on the same curve but not exactly so, then you would have an overdetermined system, and no logistic function could include all 5 points.